# sort javascript array by another related value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a challenge sorting an array as desired;

Below is my code:

```
callbacks : {
    onComplete : function(id, filename, response) {                     
        handler.addImage({
            uuid :          response.image_id,
            thumbnailUrl :  response.image_url,
            name :          response.filename
        }, id);
        this.setDeleteFileParams({
            id : response.image_id
        }, id);
        self._images.push(response.image_id); /* here */
    }
}
```

`self._images` returns an array with `response.image_id` but they are not sorted as expected;  I need the result ordered by `response.filename`.

The following example illustrates what I meant;

Given that:

```
response.image_id -> response.image_id
  8870 -> img03.jpg
  8889 -> img02.jpg
  8875 -> img01.jpg
```

The result of my function will be:

```
Array(3)
 0: 8889
 1: 8875
 2: 8870
```

Instead, this I what I would like to achieve:

```
Array(3)
 0: 8875
 1: 8889
 2: 8870
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Where did you try sorting the values ? I do not see any sorting code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of constructing an array of `image_id`s, you could construct an array of objects that have both the `filename` and `image_id` properties.

```
self._images.push({
  filename: response.filename,
  image_id: response.image_id
});
```

Now that you have the `filename` property, you can sort your array using it.

```
self._images.sort((a, b) => a.filename.localeCompare(b.filename));
```

If you want to just get an array of `image_id`, you can use the native `.map()` method.

```
self._images.map(image => image.image_id)
```

Comment: hi bennet, thank you for your help
first and second functions ir working (push and sort)
but map is not returning the array searched

I got:
0: {filename: "AN1636-02.jpeg", image_id: 313392}
1: {filename: "AN1636-03.jpeg", image_id: 313383}
2: {filename: "AN1636-04.jpeg", image_id: 313385}

But I need:
0: 313392
1: 313383
2: 313385

Comment: `.map()` returns a new array and doesn't change the original. So you'd have to do `const imageIds = self._images.map(image => image.image_id)` and then use the new array `imageIds`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of objects like so:

```
const objs = [
  {8870: "img03.jpg"},
  {8889: "img02.jpg"},
  {8875: "img01.jpg"}
];
```

You can use `Object.values` and `.sort()` with `.localeCompare()` to sort this array of objects. The `Object.values` method will give you all the values within a given object. Since all your objects in the array only have one value, we can target index `0` of this array. `.localeCompare` allows us to compare two strings and sort them using the `.sort()` method.

See working example below:

```js
const objs = [{
    8870: "img03.jpg"
  },
  {
    8889: "img02.jpg"
  },
  {
    8875: "img01.jpg"
  }
],

res = objs.sort((a, b) => Object.values(a)[0].localeCompare(Object.values(b)[0]));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the native sort function in javascript (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp).

Using this you are able to identify a sorting function in the argument. Try something like:

```
response.sort(function(responseA, responseB){return responseA.filename-responseB.filename});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self._images.push(response.image_id); /* here */
```

In your code above you are only pushing ID and you also need to push filenames . you need to make array of objects with both filename and id. then can sort as below

```
 self._images.sort((a,b) => a.filename > b.filename)
```